# Proving that if $f$ is not continuous functional then $\ker f$ is dense

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

In the context of a first course in functional analysis I have seen
the following exercise:

> Let $X$ be a normed space and $0\neq f$ a functional. Prove that if $f$
>   is not continuous then $\ker f$ is dense.

I saw a solution by another student that starts with:

> $f$ is not continuous. The set  $$ \{|f(x)|\,,x\in X\text{ and
>  }\|x\| =1\} $$
>
> is not bounded from above.

Can someone please explain how this conclusion was made?

If it weren't for the condition $\|x\|=1$ I could have taken a big
scalar $\alpha$ to get a large $|f(x)|$, but with this condition
I don't have an idea for why this is true.

Alternatively, I would also be glad to hear about a solution using a different approach.

Comment: Do you mean functional or linear functional?

Comment: If the set $\{\lvert f(x)\rvert : \lVert x\rVert = 1\}$ were bounded above, say by $C$, then $f$ would be continuous, you'd have $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert \leqslant C\cdot \lVert x-y\rVert$ for all $x,y\in X$.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian - the question doesn't say, but from the context it seems to be linear

Comment: @DanielFischer - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is, that in general for a *linear* map $T \colon X \to Y$ between normed vector spaces (i) $T$ being continuous is equivalent to (ii) $\{\|Tx\| \mid \|x\| = 1\}$ being bounded.

To see this note: If (ii) holds, we have for $x,y \in X$ with $C$ being any upper bound for the set in (ii) : 
$$ \|Tx - Ty\| \le C \|x-y\|$$
so $T$ is (Lipschitz) continuous.

On the other side, if (i) holds, $T$ is continuous at $0$, so there is $\delta > 0$ such that $\|x\|\le \delta$ implies $\|Tx\| \le 1$, given any $x \in X$ with $\|x\| = 1$, we have 
$$ \|T(\delta x)\| \le 1 \iff \|Tx \| \le \frac 1\delta, $$
so $\delta^{-1}$ is an upper bound.